# Bug Ext JS 7.4.0 Ext.grid.feature.AdvancedGrouping

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have used the Multigroup plugin and I have around 500 records that are updated every 10 seconds through a websocket:

```
updateDevices: function (array) {
    var i, store, entity;
    store = Ext.getStore('Devices');
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        entity = store.getById(array[i].id);
        if (entity) {
            entity.set({
                status: array[i].status,
                lastUpdate: array[i].lastUpdate
            }, {
                dirty: false
            });
        }  
    }
}
```

The panel renders fine, but when I try to click on the groups the click event does not work, I have to click more than 3 times to scroll the data, likewise to select a cell I have to click several times to make it appear select.

[MultiGroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtRoZ.png)
[MultiGroups Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7RKE.gif)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please, provide some fiddle sample.

Comment: Sounds like you are getting enough records in a short time, so that JS is buisy enough sorting things out. Can you privde a screenshot of the JS activity? Oh - and a fiddle ;)